Shock absorber rusted from being outside
My mountain bike has got a front shock absorber that is frozen up.
I have tried the following:
The best rust remover.
Knocking it with a hammer to loosen it.
What else can I try?


I agree with @Rеnаud 's for some reason self deleted answer! Do not try to unsieze the fork. Do not ride it in rough terrain or dangerous roads. Progressively try on different obstacles as to gauge how far you can push it and still keep You teeth. After all that cough up a hundred bucks for a new fork and enjoy it.

@Vorac It looks like you think the worst. I like to be a good steward of my money.

This fork will be gone, really. The stanchion surfaces also look scratched and for them it is a real problem. And they will be affected by the rust. Suspension forks require some regular maintenance and if not the regular service (especially for air ones) they at least need the dirt to be cleaned and the surfaces to be greased by silicone oil or some shock-specific oil. For quality forks that do receive the regular service every 50 h, additional grease may be unnecessary, but this one has likely never seen such a service.
You can try some rust removal grease (which should normally not come there!) like WD40 and let it do its work for several hours, but I would not have any high hopes.

@fixit7 could you please expand on that?  What point are you disagreeing with?   Is it that your question is "how to disassemble" when this answer suggests that the stanchion sliding surfaces already look ruined ?

@Criggie I am not ready to give up getting that fork loose. Even if I have to drill it out or some other way.

@fixit7 I'm sure you'll get it apart, be it with a hammer or jack or grinder.  Whether it will be serviceable afterward, thats a separate problem.   When you do get it apart, please post pictures.

@Criggie Try to think positive. :-)

For now, I decided to ride it as is  Someone suggested doing a wheelie to try to loosen it. :-) I am using a chain cleaner. So far it has taken 3 refills. When I put my bike outside I used a metal protection spray that was recommended. Considering it has been outside covered from direct rain, the rust is quite minimal. There are some spider webs and dead plant growth that needed cleaning. My bike speedometer is still working after 11 months.

There is a YouTube video here on repairing rusted seized RST Gila T5 Fork/Shocks.
